# Early '90s CGI short film about insects living inside a computer

Tags: story-identification, animation, short-film, cgi

This has been driving me crazy for years. In the early '90s, I remember seeing a CGI short film. It’s about a kid who gets a computer game, but when he starts playing, something goes wrong and the game crashes the computer. The kid throws it out and then we are focusing on the story of what’s going on inside the computer.

Apparently it is inhabited by digital “bugs”. I remember a spider is the main one, with some other bugs (grasshopper, fly, etc). They are upset that their home is being thrown out and look to save the computer. They do, and the kid takes it back inside and happy ending.

Sadly I can’t remember anything else, like dialogue, but this is stuck in my head and I desperately need a title to ease my mind. All I remember about it specifically is seeing a commercial about a “Honey I Shrunk the Kids” theme park attraction about the same time. Which would place it late '80s or early '90s. Please help if you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just started searching for a VHS tape that I remember seeing as a child and I remember it containing the short you are looking for. After a lot of digging through the Mind's Eye series and spinoffs, I discovered the tape I was looking for was **Computer Animation Festival 2.0**. The name of the short you described is **Computer Home**. Here's a version on YouTube, though it's split across two different videos. The first link is timestamped to the start of **Computer Home**:

1st half:

2nd half:

Comment: My dude! You have no idea the relief this brings me! Thank you a thousand times over! This has seriously been plaguing my mind for 30 years. I can rest east now. You are the best! Thank you again!

Comment: @Betty -- if this is the answer to your question, as implied by your comment, please click the checkbox to accept the answer.