# Early 90s CGI short involving a camouflaged (not cloaked) Romulan or Klingon ship shooting down a fighter jet

Tags: story-identification, animation, short-film, cgi

This is, admittedly, a secondhand query, but one that I think I will recognize on seeing it and seeing [Early '90s CGI short film about insects living inside a computer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262499/early-90s-cgi-short-film-about-insects-living-inside-a-computer) answered made me bold enough to think someone might have an answer to this one. In the early 1990s, my brother went to a computer show, and came back describing an animation he'd seen demonstrated. The early part of the animation showed a fighter jet wending its way through canyons, flying in a very [nap of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nap-of-the-earth) fashion, with the end of the animation having a spacecraft rising off of a cliff wall and firing a shot that took the fighter jet down. I remember distinctly what he made the point that the spacecraft was not cloaked or otherwise invisible, but just painted in such a way that it blended perfectly with the background such that you didn't see it until it fired.

Part of me wants to say that he explicitly called out [3D Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_3ds_Max) as having been used to make the video, but I could just be thinking about that in the context of that it was the accepted 3D software at the time.

In retrospect, it seems that a fighter jet would be travelling too fast for it to make narrative sense for a stationary camouflaged ship and the jet to be in the same frame for more than a second, but I could see it either being that sort of a split-second thing (spaceship rises off of the surface and fires as the jet is passing by, just leaving flaming wreckage) or if perhaps it were handled in a more cinematic scene, cutting between the flying jet, the spaceship rising and firing, and the jet being destroyed midflight.

And honestly, I don't know if my brother specifically mentioned it being a Klingon or Romulan vessel, or if I just assumed it based on him talking about the spaceship not being "cloaked", *Star Trek* being a very popular show for us at the time. My brother does not remember this story, so he hasn't been much help tracking this down.

Comment: There is some similarity to the demogroup *Rage*'s "Alchemy" demo (1993). Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkbTWoZ4voc (starting 4:07 in.) The second ship doesn't actually shoot down the first - a rather silly *deus ex machina* involving Darth Vader happens at about 6:24 in.

Comment: Which *Star Trek* series were you both into at the time? DS9? TNG?

Comment: Blurry though it is, there's a demo of a Silicon Graphics workstation being used in N64 development, and the footage from 2:10 on in this video *might* be a match? I'm pessimistic, but: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKlbx5niBu8

Comment: Which city/state do you remember this computer show being in? And do you remember what time of the year this roughly was? (e.g. summer, autumn?) Does your brother remember what sort of hardware it was running on? IBM PC, Silicon Graphics, Sun workstations...

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern: I'll run the first clip by my brother, but the latter one seems a bit far in the future. We would have just been transitioning from ST:TOS to ST:TNG at the time. And this would have been in Ashland, KY, I think running on one of the machines at the Community College (although it was a demo setup, so they might have brought in outside machines).

Comment: Won't put it as an answer yet, but it was very common, especially in those days (my old days) to make up animations just for shows or reels. They would be in house or software merchant specific and only for trade show demonstrations, because if they went further they would be called out for similarity to copyrighted material, and yes things like copies of star trek objects might turn up for the sake of saving time. So its possible it might never be found again..

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks. TNG started in the late 80s, not early 90s. Could it have been then that your brother saw this?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Does your brother remember what sort of computer show this was? Some sort of trade show? A [demoparty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene#Parties)?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots You may want to take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TwzhNxDjTU - 9:45 until 10:10.

Comment: Also, as well as a trade show or demoparty... could this have been students at the college who'd studied 3d animation showing off their class projects?

Comment: Does your brother remember anything about the shape of the fighter jet? Delta wing or straight wing (or one of those really cool swing-wings?) One tail and one engine like the [F-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-16_Fighting_Falcon)? Two tails and one engine like the [F-35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II)? Two tails and two engines like the [F-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-22_Raptor)?

Comment: :) I will check with him, although the space of two decades might hamper details.

Comment: Might be worth checking on what the quality of the CGI might have been like: As an example, I recall being at trade shows and watching this: youtu.be/2PS5zRFiSwQ as the Alias guys and girls ply me with flyers and drink. This is Autodesk 3D studio in 1993: youtu.be/OREOCweJ-xQ - see the obvious nod at the beginning...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Do you or your brother remember exactly which year he saw it? Or at least, which years in the early 90s it might have been?

Comment: Additionally, could there have been a river running through the bottom of the canyon?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I may have found the answer. Can you show your brother [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOp_OxNdAoU), which has a fighter plane flying through a canyon at 01:54, 02:21 and 03:30. It also has the plane, or another plane, flying through the sky a good bit faster in some places. Ask if the canyon looks like it might have been the one. Also the plane, although the software package I have in mind had multiple different fighter jets. Also show him [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGI_Dogfight#Sci-fi_craft,_World_War_1_planes,_and_the_X-29).

Comment: If it might be a match, I'll type up a full answer. Note in particular another part of the Wikipedia page mentioning "airshow mode", likely used to create a video of actual play.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern nice find! looks like the ticket! I recall SGI showing all these demos off to me (though I do not remember this one) in truck trailer demo booths (when not at conventions) - only to actually be using them years later.. ;P - towards the end, I didn't play Flight, I played Doom instead..

Comment: @blobbymcblobby Well, due to the copyright-infringing planes being added, SGI wouldn't have shown *this* version! But I've seen a good few vids with people demonstrating a few seconds worth of *Doom*, *Quake* or *Quake III* on their SGI machines.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern - thats fair, though always thought there was a 'rebellious schoolkid' element at conventions where this kind of thing.. might have got through, towards the 'end of the day' kind of thing (after the directors had left)... Since actually using SGI's for flight simulations I think I thought Doom was a rather more fun way to kill time (and colleagues) in those days!

Comment: That does look promising.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots OK. I'll turn this into a full answer when I get time - hopefully later today but it may be next week.

Comment: Part of the reason it may be next week is that I've emailed people who had copies of this, or who had Silicon Graphics magazines that mentioned (or maybe had photos?) of it, and I want to give them time to respond. However, I may post the answer in anyway and then edit in their information as I receive it.

Comment: Update on previous comment - of the two emails I sent, I've had one reply so far. Sadly, he no longer has a copy of the relevant magazine issue. Still waiting on the other person.

Comment: I haven't yet had a response to email 2, so I've typed up my answer and posted it now instead of waiting any longer.

Comment: I **may** have found another possible contender - Artificial Horizons Inc.'s "Aviator" as mentioned at https://groups.google.com/g/comp.sys.sgi.misc/c/DKVVMEgO-0g/m/X4vjteZBMBYJ . The Grand Canyon as a location, 1989 release date and the build-your-own-plane-model option (as a way of creating the Klingon craft) all fit. Apparently this ran on Sun SPARCs. Unfortunately, it's a LOT harder to find videos or screenshots of!

Comment: Or, for that matter, any sort of discussion forum for users of old SPARCstations! Does anybody know of one? I'm going to try Reddit's r/retrobattlestations and r/vintagecomputing .

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ is a possibility as well for this question

Comment: Looks like there's at least one other place I can ask - the "Vintage Computer Federation Forums" - based on https://forum.vcfed.org/index.php?threads/anybody-here-actually-collect-unix-stuff.2481/page-4 . Also, forums.sgi.sh does have a section devoted to other old Unix workstations, with a subsection for Sun. I'm going to start by asking there.

Comment: I've posted a request for screenshots and footage, along with information on "Aviator" to https://forums.sgi.sh/index.php?threads/aviator-a-flight-sim-program-for-sun-gx-does-anyone-have-this-installed-can-anyone-run-it-and-get-screenshots-or-video.885/ . I haven't posted to Reddit's r/retrobattlestations yet, as I'm not quite sure this is within that group's remit.

Comment: Also posted to Reddit's r/vintagecomputing: https://old.reddit.com/r/vintagecomputing/comments/y4wo6b/a_request_to_owners_of_sparcstations_and_other/? . It's getting a bit late now, so I'll log off for the night and post to the vcfed.org forums tomorrow.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots About your statement that *a fighter jet would be travelling too fast for it to make narrative sense for a stationary camouflaged ship and the jet to be in the same frame for more than a second* - It looks like "slow flight" by fighter jets is actually a real thing, not just a quirk of this animation or of SGI's software! See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH5Cf9rvBc0 and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/why-are-fighter-jets-so-loud-when-doing-slow-flight

Comment: @blobbymcblobby Looks like you're right about that "rebellious schoolkid element" - I just found [this comment on Bytecellar](https://bytecellar.com/2019/10/07/sgi-o2-promo-video-from-the-mid-90s/#comment-1394673): *"I was a sysadmin and field service tech for SGI during those years, ranging from the Impact2 up through O2 and Octane. The highlight was when I got to MC the Onyx Truck. This was an Onyx Reality Monster built into a tractor trailer and we gave public demos of the multi screen flight simulator running inside. We also used to do "illegal" stunts for product demos, like"* 1/

Comment: *"configuring a dual-head Impact2 with two Maximum Impact graphics boards. This technically exceeded the thermal and power limits of the case, but it would do it for short periods. There was nothing like SGI in the 90s. Amazing stuff. Then 3dfx came along, Voodoo ate our lunch for 1/10th the price, and just like that it was all over."*

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern !Ha! Good find! :) Yes, I was shown demos on those trucks - SGI were pushing hard I guess in those days - and I went to the conventions too, I think thats where I got the vague memory of that kind thing going on. Great read, again! :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe this to be a version of [SGI Dogfight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGI_Dogfight) (usually just known as *dog* or *flight* to SGI/Silicon Graphics enthusiasts.)

More precisely, I believe this to be an unauthorised mod of the game that was created, and spread, in violation of the NDA [Silicon Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Graphics) placed on the game's source code. This mod added X-Wings, TIE Fighters and [Klingon battlecruisers from TOS-era Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_starships#The_Original_Series_era) to the set of available planes, as well as two WW1-era craft and the Grumman X-29. Since the original set of planes included four different types of fighter jet, this means that a Klingon battlecruiser and a fighter plane *could* have fought each other in-game.

More information on this mod is available from these links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGI_Dogfight#Sci-fi_craft,_World_War_1_planes,_and_the_X-29
- https://groups.google.com/g/comp.sys.sgi.misc/c/m3mdKtouN1E/m/nnRM6jzWgWoJ

  > We are just about to retire a SGI 3130. I have a version of dog on that machine that has the following vehicles:
  >
  > X-Wing Fighter has lasers
  >
  > Tie Fighter with Snoopy Pilot has lasers
  >
  > Sopwith Camel with Snoopy Pilot
  >
  > Folkner Tri-Plane with Snoopy Pilot
  >
  > X-29
  > Klingon Battle Cruiser (ala the Original Star Trek) has Photon Torpedoes
  > and Phasers.
  >
  > Plus the usual vehicles: P-38, F-16, F-15, etc.
- https://groups.google.com/g/comp.sys.sgi/c/918KyFAs6Jk/m/omOpRckB8xUJ

  > So how does one get the version of flight with the Klingon ship that blows craters in the Earth and also has an x-wing fighter? I got the source demo tape from Monica Schultz (?) and requested the above but only got normal every day flight
- https://groups.google.com/g/comp.sys.sgi/c/gYNWp8qbKpA/m/4zE_3EcGPjsJ

  > > *BTW, I've heard that there are all sorts of "planes" at Mountain View,*
  > > *including Snoopy's Doghouse (?) Perhaps these could be made available*
  > > *FTP?*
  >
  > There is a version of the old flight from a university with a bunch of unusual planes(X-wing, Tie-fighter, Klingon). This can not be shipped by SGI as these are copyrighted things. One of the first demos was snoopy on a doghouse flying around. We were soon contacted and told we could not use it.

(The reference to "Mountain View" above is because that's where SGI's headquarters were at the time. In fact, [Google's Mountain View campus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googleplex#SGI_Campus) is exactly the same one Silicon Graphics used to have! There are some cool photos [here](https://wiki.preterhuman.net/SGI_Buildings) and [here](https://sgihardware.tumblr.com/post/641829174920806400/silicon-graphics-inc-headquarters-in-1998).)

**EDIT/MAJOR UPDATE: I recently found a scan of two pages from SGI's old in-house magazine, IRIS Universe, containing more information on this mod:**

[image: IRIS Universe Fall 1987 Pages 16 and 17]

The above scan reveals that it was created at the University of Toronto, that the author was one Shannon McKenzie, and that at one time (presumably before lawyers objected) SGI didn't mind about the NDA violation and were willing to distribute the modded version to anyone who wrote in asking for it! It also contains a black-and-white screenshot of the game's X-Wing model.

**END OF EDIT.**

I'll be relying heavily on two Youtube videos as sources. One of them is from 1990. The other has no date on it, but must have been filmed between 1988 and mid-September 1991. I'll explain why later.

From [the first video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOp_OxNdAoU), starting at 01:54:

[image] [image] [image]

Here we see a fighter plane flying through a canyon, as described. Maybe even low-altitude enough to count as "nap of the earth".

> In retrospect, it seems that a fighter jet would be travelling too fast for it to make narrative sense for a stationary camouflaged ship and the jet to be in the same frame for more than a second

If you watch the video, you'll notice that it's flying *very* slowly - in fact, unusually slowly given that it's meant to be a fighter jet! But this wasn't slowed down footage. The jet really was flying that slowly in the software. In messages at the end of the video, the following text was displayed:

[image: All of the computer imagery in this presentation, shown at actual speed, was produced in real-time on Silicon Graphics workstations.]

> *All of the computer imagery in this presentation, shown at actual speed, was produced in real-time on Silicon Graphics workstations.*

The game offered four fighter jets as options (as well as other planes like a Cessna C150 and Boeing 747.) The twin-engine, two-tailed plane you see in the screenshots could have been any one of the F-14, F-15 or F-18. Having no way of playing the game myself, I can't tell you which of them it would have been. But I suspect the F-14, since [this Usenet thread](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.sys.sgi/c/IBfMvDa-Xv8/m/nzve39V68QcJ) mentions "the skeleton mark on the tail of F-14", and since the black tails with yellow lines on top match a picture from [this site](https://notwood.net/sgiflight/):

[image]

(NB: I have tried to run that Windows port under Wine on Linux, but it fails every time.)

Now, let's look at screenshots from the [second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9KhD_pj9DU), starting at 1:27 in:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Once again, we have a strangely slow-moving fighter jet, and this time there is some other craft in the distance. Whatever this craft is, it's too small and blurry to say for sure, but it appears to consist of two segments with the front one smaller than the rear. Of all the planes in the original set, plus the craft added by the mod, a Klingon battlecruiser is the closest match for this shape - in fact, it's the only one I would say has a good match. Though I still would have expected the wings to stick out a bit more - maybe it's the angle it's viewed from?

***NOTE:*** This is not hard evidence that you're seeing the Klingon craft in this particular video. It could be, for instance, that what we're seeing there is the twin engines of another fighter jet seen from behind. The rest of the jet, being light grey, would blend with the sky and be less visible.

And once again, the fighter jet was indeed moving that slowly in the actual software on the SGI - because the second video showed the same message as the first:

[image: All of the computer imagery in this presentation, shown at actual speed, was produced in real-time on Silicon Graphics workstations.]

> *All of the computer imagery in this presentation, shown at actual speed, was produced in real-time on Silicon Graphics workstations.*

From the interview starting at 03:35 in this video, we can tell that it was filmed when Tom Jermoluk was still vice president of the Advanced Systems Division (i.e. between 1988 and 1991, according to [Crunchbase](https://www.crunchbase.com/person/tom-jermoluk)). He was promoted to a different role at some point prior to September 17 1991, according to [this source](http://www.sgistuff.net/hardware/graphics/documents/iris-gl-announce.txt).

So between this and the first video, I'd say the most likely year for your brother to have seen this is 1990, with 1991 being the second most likely. And one of those years would also fit in with his being impressed by what he saw. Because after that...

- **1992:** [Virtua Racing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtua_Racing#/media/File:Virtua_Racing_screenshot_2007.png) shows up in arcades.
- **1993:** [Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_(1993_video_game)) arrives on home PCs. [Ridge Racer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_Racer_(1993_video_game)) and [Virtua Fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtua_Fighter_(video_game)) come to the arcade.

... and those games *massively* raised the bar for 3D graphics in the early 90s!

> came back describing an animation he'd seen demonstrated.

You mention your brother seeing an animation, not someone playing the game, so it might be that the video you saw was the software using its **-i** option to read files containing the flightpaths of various aeroplanes from earlier playthroughs, and then replay them. But I don't know if planes being "replayed" in this fashion could interact with other planes, so there may still have been human players operating the two craft you saw, since one was able to shoot the other down.

Note also that *dog* was a very early example of a networked game, so one of the players might have been sitting at another workstation somewhere your brother didn't see.

Or maybe someone filmed a video of the game, and your brother saw a promotional VHS playing. Or an SGI machine playing a video file.

So... would SGI actually have shown this illicit version of their tech demo game to impress people? Hard to say. But they certainly knew about it. I'll repeat this quote from earlier:

> There is a version of the old flight from a university with a bunch of
> unusual planes(X-wing, Tie-fighter, Klingon). This can not be shipped by
> SGI as these are copyrighted things. One of the first demos was snoopy
> on a doghouse flying around. We were soon contacted and told we could not use it.

([source](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.sys.sgi/c/gYNWp8qbKpA/m/4zE_3EcGPjsJ))

That quote was from Rob Mace, who took over as lead developer for *flight* when Gary Tarolli moved on to other things.

Finally, here's another picture - just to show that the quality of the graphics was a bit inconsistent. Note the texture mapping on the green hills versus the flat colour on the purple ones and the ground:

[image]

The game was officially forked to allow for more sophisticated graphics on the GT, GTX and VGX machines, but even then I suspect there was internal inconsistency as new terrain and features were added many years later than the original assets.

Comment: The geometry of that plane screams [F-14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F-14_Tomcat).  Both the [F-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-15_Eagle) and [F-18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet) have their engines significantly closer together.

Comment: @PeterM Many thanks for that. And since I have a bit of a fondness for swing-wing planes, I'm very glad it was the F-14!

Comment: @PeterM Though the manpages for some versions did have a **"Bugs"** section, which stated: *"In the GT/GTX/VGX version, the F15 looks like a F14 with the wings swept back."*. So it could have been the F-15.

Comment: Fantastic write up!

Comment: @blobbymcblobby Thanks! It took a lot of research to get to this point.

Comment: I *may* have found another possible contender - Artificial Horizons Inc.'s "Aviator" as mentioned at https://groups.google.com/g/comp.sys.sgi.misc/c/DKVVMEgO-0g/m/X4vjteZBMBYJ . The Grand Canyon as a location, 1989 release date and the build-your-own-plane-model option all fit. Apparently this ran on Sun SPARCs.

Comment: I ran it by him at the family gathering and he doesn't remember, but agrees that it looks plausible.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I've started looking into AHI's "Aviator", and I've posted requests in a few places for owners of old Sun GX hardware to take some screenshots or footage of it. Perhaps the Grand Canyon and fighter plane graphics in *that* game might jog his memory - let's cross our fingers and hope so!

Comment: If you should find a better answer, let me know, but until now, this is probably as close as I'm going to get to as an answer. I get the impression that this made a larger impression on me than on my brother.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Someone on Reddit's r/vintagecomputing has gotten Aviator 1.5.1 running on an old SPARCstation 20, and they're trying to get it to use the 1.2 terrain data (which includes the Grand Canyon). So there *might* be another answer posted soon. Plus, although I've only just got the confirmation email issues on vcfed.org sorted, there were a few people reminiscing about Aviator there, and it was a user of that site who posted freeware 1.2 and the demo version of 1.5.1 to the Internet, so I have high hopes for there. So... I think the green tick *may* have been a bit premature.

Comment: It's easily changed, but I can remove it if you like.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a scan from the old "IRIS Universe" magazine (SGI's house publication.) It reveals that the university this mod was created at was the University of Toronto, and that its creator was one Shannon McKenzie. I have done some searching and Mr. McKenzie does have an online presence - https://ca.linkedin.com/in/shannon-mckenzie-9498801 and https://www.facebook.com/shannon.b.mckenzie.9/ - but no apparent way to contact him other than via those two sites. I do not have either a Facebook or LinkedIn account and really DO NOT WANT to be on FB. If someone has an 1/

Comment: account on either of those sites, would they be willing to send him a message to see if he still has the source code for this version of *flight* (and/or a compiled binary blob?) I also note from his Facebook page that he's been looking for work since October 2021, despite a long and varied career in game development, so if you know of any suitable Canadian software firms with vacancies PLEASE let him know! Some old SGI stuff sells for a fortune on eBay nowadays, so if he has any old hardware from then, please tell him to check eBay prices as he could sell for a lot of money!